# How can I determine that a function is bounded?

Tags: functions, logarithms, circles

Let $\Omega:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:x^2 +y^2 \leq 1 \}$ and let $$f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$ with $$f(x,y)=\log(\log(\frac{1}{r}))$$ for $$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

How can i determine that this function is bounded?

**My effort**:

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2) \cdot \log(x^2+y^2)} $$

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2) \cdot \log(x^2+y^2)} $$

\begin{align*}
 \frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2) \cdot \log(x^2+y^2)} &=0 \\
 \frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2) \cdot \log(x^2+y^2)} &=0
\end{align*}

Therefore : \begin{align*}
2x&=0 \\
2y&=0
\end{align*}

So $x=0,y=0$ is function is unbounded.

**Questions**
**1)** Am I right ?

**2)** $f \in L^2(\Omega) $

in order t be  $L^2(\Omega)$ must have a finite integral $$\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx < \infty$$ so it's not $L^2$

**3)** $f \in H^1(\Omega) $

no because there is no weak derivative  $f = 0$ at the endpoints $a$ and $b$
Since $\phi$ has not a compact support (i.e., bounded and closed),

Comment: At the point $0$, your function explodes to infinity and is not bounded.

Comment: Calculus can be used to determine bounds for functions on domains.  For instance, if you can find its global maximum and minimum, the function is bounded between them.  But often you can infer boundedness from the function's definition.

Comment: To find the global extrema of a function, finding the stationary points is not sufficient. You also have to look at the boundary of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the logarithm is unbounded for $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$. Then you have $$r\le1,$$
$$\frac1r\ge1,$$
$$\log\frac1r\ge0$$
and
$$\log\log\frac1r$$ is unbounded.